# Pandas column name coming in two levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My initial Dataframe:
[image: initial DF]

Hi, I was doing one assignment, after Dataframe melt operation followed by group by and count, I find some interesting thing when I did the later operations :

```
melted_df = df.melt(id_vars= 'cardio',value_vars=['cholesterol'     ,'gluc' ,   'smoke' ,   'alco' ,    'active' ,  'overweight'])


melted_df = pd.DataFrame(melted_df.groupby(['cardio' ,  'variable' ,    'value'])['value'].count())
```

After this operation the columns divided into two levels like this :

[image]

> I am only able to rename the 1st level names, not the lower levels.
>
> Can someone explain why there are two levels ?

Comment: interesting. What are the unique values for "value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `as_index` parameter.

```
pd.DataFrame(melted_df.groupby(['cardio' ,  'variable' ,    'value'], as_index=False)['value'].count())
```

The problem occurs because you put an existing dataframe as data into a new dataframe:

Is there a reason you don't do this?

```
melted_df = melted_df.groupby(['cardio' ,  'variable' ,    'value'], as_index=False)['value'].count()
```

Based on the request in your comment:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\test\medical_examination.csv")
df = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'cardio'], value_vars=['cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco', 'active'])
df = df.groupby(['cardio', 'variable', 'value'])['value'].agg(total=sum).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply,but my question was what does both level signifies ? 
I already have a solution to the problem but my confusion is the above line :D 
Can you pls tell me why it create different levels of column name ?

Comment: Hi @Andreas , actually I want to do something like this : https://imgur.com/a/0OiifjH

Any better way to do this ?

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta Hmm, can you provide the dataset or a simple copy paste example? E.g. use df.iloc[:20].to_dict() and post the dictionary here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a_ujhLD8c2WDsVupOW4Jy-_ywVBmxSEP/view?usp=sharing

here is the data set

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta ahhh, I adjusted my answer once again.